# Using rails mailer how can choose template from sendgrid Legacy Email Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, actionmailer, sendgrid

I have created templates in sendgrid, How I need to choose in my rails application while delivering emails

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base   
  include SendGrid
  ...
  def welcome_user
    mail(:to => 'xxx@gmail.com' , :subject => "Welcome to our website.")   
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Legacy Email Templates](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/email_templates.html) doesn't have multiple templates to choose from. If you created multiple templates, you need to use the [Template Engine](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/template_engine.html).

For either implementation, you'll want to use the [SMTPAPI Gem](https://github.com/SendGridJP/smtpapi-ruby) to build the appropriate SMTPAPI header. You can define which [Template Engine template to use in SMTPAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/smtpapi.html), as well as [activate the Legacy Template app](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html#templates).